# How exactly does the window size work in a TCP communication?

Tags: untagged

I know what Flow Control and Sliding Window is in TCP. The window size specified by the receiver tells the sender how many bytes of data can the sender send before waiting for an ACK.

I always thought that communication in a TCP session works like this

Sender --> sends as much data as possible to the receiver, filling up the sender's window and then waits for an ACK

Receiver --> ACKs the data once its window size has been fully filled so the sender can send more if necessary.

However, during my Wireshark captures, there have been numerous cases where the receiver sent an ACK before its window size was fully filled. How exactly does this work?